# Querying multiple date based tables in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, tableau-api

I'm new to Tableau and BigQuery and have just linked the two.  However I'm having trouble with the TABLE_DATE_RANGE - which would allow me to join the tables over specific time period.

This query works in BQ:

SELECT fullVisitorId FROM  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([78004876.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2014-08-01'),TIMESTAMP('2014-08-19')));

however not in Tableau.  When I replace with parameters it just errors out.

SELECT fullVisitorId FROM  (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([78004876.ga_sessions_],,);

error:  Encountered " ";" ";"" at line 1, column 156
Was expecting: ")" ...

any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the semicolon? I know Tableau likes to wrap custom SQL inside a nested SELECT before sending off to BQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.  It looks as if you are trying to make the dates flexible in Tableau.  If this is the case, all you need to do is add a few parameters to your Tableau file for the **begining** and **ending** date.  After which, your query would actually look something like this:

```
SELECT fullVisitorId FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([78004876.ga_sessions_],<Parameters.Start_Date>,<Parameters.End_Date>);
```

Additionally, you had an orphaned "(" symbol after the "FROM" Keyword that I removed

**Also Note:** You must create the parameters and give them valid values (Actual tables that exist in your Big Query Data-set) before connecting to the data source.